# Passing CAST(foo AS type) as a relationship condition in DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbix-class

For historical reasons, we have a table at work that has integer values in a text field that correspond to the ID's in another table.  Example:

```
CREATE TABLE things (
    id     INTEGER,
    name   VARCHAR,
    thingy VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE other_things (
    id     INTEGER,
    name   VARCHAR,
);
```

So a "thing" has-one "other thing", but rather than being set up sensibly, the join field is a varchar, and called "thingy".

So in Postgres, I can do this to join the two tables:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, ot.name FROM things t 
  JOIN other_things ot ON CAST(t.thingy AS int) = ot.id
```

How can I represent this relationship in DBIx::Class?  Here's an example of one thing I've tried:

```
package MySchema::Thing;

__PACKAGE__->has_one(
    'other_thing',
    'MySchema::OtherThing',
    { 'foreign.id' => 'CAST(self.thingy AS int)' },
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nwellnhof was close, but to get the literal SQL to SQL::Abstract, I had to do a coderef like so:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_one(
    'other_thing',
    'MySchema::OtherThing',
    sub {
        my $args = shift;
        return {
            qq{$args->{'foreign_alias'}.id} => { q{=} => \qq{CAST($args->{'self_alias'}.dept AS int)} },
        };  
    },
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Literal SQL](https://metacpan.org/module/SQL::Abstract#Literal-SQL) should do the trick:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_one(
    'other_thing',
    'MySchema::OtherThing',
    { 'foreign.id' => { '=', \'CAST(self.thingy AS int)' } },
);
```

Comment: Gives me "Invalid rel cond SCALAR(...)".  :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd change the datatype of the field.

If that's not possible you could add another field of type int and a trigger that casts the varchar to an int and stores it in the int field that you then use for the joins to improve performance.